# How to extract values from matrices based on category?

Tags: r

I have 3 matrices `B` is category of numbers while `m1` and `m2` are different values.
I want to extract values from `m1` and `m2` for each category (number) in `B`. I create cols for each category (number) in B and name them with their numbers,then fill it with corresponding values from `m1` and `m2`

```
 B = matrix(  c(2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1,3,1),   nrow=4,  ncol=2)
 m1<-matrix(nrow=4,ncol=2,data=runif(8))
 m2<-matrix(nrow=4,ncol=2,data=runif(8))
       > B
           [,1] [,2]
    [1,]    2    2
    [2,]    3    1
    [3,]    3    3
    [4,]    1    1
   > m1
              [,1]      [,2]
     [1,] 0.02628084 0.7286645
     [2,] 0.48612723 0.5551138
     [3,] 0.54268103 0.0734144
     [4,] 0.83666012 0.1365023
       > m2
      [,1]       [,2]
     [1,] 0.9753650 0.01225462
     [2,] 0.3843785 0.64147320
     [3,] 0.4886735 0.51257497
     [4,] 0.4907762 0.32035212
```

desired output:

```
                  2                            3                1
0.02628084(#corresponding value from m1)    0.48612723    0.83666012
0.9753650(#corresponding value from m2)      0.3843785      0.4907762
0.7286645 (#corresponding value from m1)    0.5551138         0.54268103
0.01225462 (#corresponding value from m2)  0.64147320     0.4886735
                                           0.0734144       0.1365023
                                           0.51257497      0.32035212
```

Comment: Please use `set.seed` when you generated random numbers.

Comment: So that your m1 and m2 would be reproducible. @bic ton See the help manual of `set.seed` for more info.

Comment: How does value `2` correspond to values `0.02628084` and `0.02628084` in the two matrices???

Comment: `B[1,1]`  corresponds to  `m1[1,1], m2[1,1], m3[1,1],  m4[1,1],………………………..`

Comment: @bicton But in which way? You have to tell us in which way so that we can implement it...

Comment: extract values in `B` that correspond to its index in other matrices

Comment: The value is `2` and the indices are `[1,1]`.....??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you happy with this solution and output format?

```
# data:
set.seed(123)
B = matrix(  c(2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1,3,1),   nrow=4,  ncol=2)
m1<-matrix(nrow=4,ncol=2,data=runif(8))
m2<-matrix(nrow=4,ncol=2,data=runif(8))


ml <- list(m1, m2)
ind <- sapply(unique(c(B)), function(x) which(B == x, arr.ind = TRUE))
res <- lapply(ind, function(x) lapply(ml, function(y) y[x]))

lapply(res, function(x) c(t(do.call(cbind, x))))
[[1]]
[1] 0.2875775 0.5514350 0.9404673 0.6775706

[[2]]
[1] 0.7883051 0.4566147 0.4089769 0.9568333 0.5281055 0.1029247

[[3]]
[1] 0.8830174 0.4533342 0.0455565 0.5726334 0.8924190 0.8998250
```

You cannot put it into a data frame or a matrix because of the different lengths of the columns.

The data used is (it would be much easier is you used `set.seed` generating the samples):

```
 m1
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.2875775 0.9404673
[2,] 0.7883051 0.0455565
[3,] 0.4089769 0.5281055
[4,] 0.8830174 0.8924190
> m2
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.5514350 0.6775706
[2,] 0.4566147 0.5726334
[3,] 0.9568333 0.1029247
[4,] 0.4533342 0.8998250
> B
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    2
[2,]    3    1
[3,]    3    3
[4,]    1    1
```

Comment: what is `ml`? in your answer

Comment: `ml` is a list containing the matrices. Look at the editted code

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want. It will give you list with the first element containing the values in `m1` and `m2` that are in the same location as the 1 in `B`. The second elements contains the value for 2, and so on.

```
set.seed(123)
B = matrix(  c(2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1,3,1),   nrow=4,  ncol=2)
m1<-matrix(nrow=4,ncol=2,data=runif(8))
m2<-matrix(nrow=4,ncol=2,data=runif(8))

values <- sort(unique(sapply(B, function(x) x)))
l <- sapply(values, function(x) c(m1[B == x], m2[B == x]))
```

To add value names:

```
names(l) <- values
```

Comment: Sounds like the `arr.ind = TRUE` option in `which` will get you close to what you want.